# Application shortcuts do not match keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, language, shortcut-menu

My MacBook language is set to French, but the physical keyboard layout is US English, therefore I am using a US layout in layout preferences.

Now, this is the problem:

[image]

The above image shows the keyboard shortcuts for the Viewer (Aperçu). The problem is that these shortcuts are totally useless when using any layout other than French AZERTY (or maybe also French Swiss Romand (QWERTZ)). Is there something I can do about this (other than change the language, or create a custom keyboard layout)?

It is worth noting that all Apple applications have this issue, notably Safari, Mail, etc.

Comment: I wonder what French speaking Canadians do, as their keyboard is much more like US than French Azerty.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that there is a fix to this. The shortcuts seem to be hardcoded to the system language setting (restart is required on change). Apple should really make the shortcuts agree with the currently enabled layout.

Comment: You might try asking on the French Apple forum:   https://communities.apple.com/fr/welcome

Comment: I have tried, but I cannot sign up in order to post the question. It always replies with "Unknown error" upon registration. So frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I asked the question on Apple Discussions, [here](https://communities.apple.com/fr/thread/220022951).

There is a solution, but requires one to manually reassign the shortcuts, one by one. Not ideal, but it's a workaround until Apple decides to take macOS development seriously again.

Anyway, the solution is here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377

Comment: …and this will be the problem with link-only answers. The link is dead, the answer is gone.